# Proportion of total in pd.NamedAgg

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pivot-table

I have a `df` like this:

| Foo | Bar |
| --- | --- |
| A | 54 |
| A | 95 |
| B | 49 |
| A | 25 |
| B | 25 |
| B | 32 |
| B | 55 |
| A | 98 |
| A | 83 |
| B | 90 |

I am computing some statistics using [`aggfunc`][1]:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Foo': {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'B',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'B',
  5: 'B',
  6: 'B',
  7: 'A',
  8: 'A',
  9: 'B'},
 'Bar': {0: 54, 1: 95, 2: 49, 3: 25, 4: 25, 5: 32, 6: 55, 7: 98, 8: 83, 9: 90}})

res_df = temp.groupby('Foo').agg(
    max_val = pd.NamedAgg(column='Bar', aggfunc='max'),
    min_val = pd.NamedAgg(column='Bar', aggfunc='min'),
    std_val = pd.NamedAgg(column='Bar', aggfunc='std')
)
```

Which results (correctly) in:

| Foo | max_val | min_val | std_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 98 | 25 | 31.0403 |
| B | 90 | 25 | 25.37124 |

However, I want to add another column which is proportion of total, so for example:

| Foo | max_val | min_val | std_val | pct_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 98 | 25 | 31.0403 | 0.59 |
| B | 90 | 25 | 25.37124 | 0.41 |

How can I accomplish this using `aggfunc`?
[1]: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as follows:

```
res_df = temp.groupby('Foo').agg(
    max_val = pd.NamedAgg(column='Bar', aggfunc='max'),
    min_val = pd.NamedAgg(column='Bar', aggfunc='min'),
    std_val = pd.NamedAgg(column='Bar', aggfunc='std'),
    pct_total = pd.NamedAgg(column='Bar', aggfunc=lambda x: x.sum()/temp.Bar.sum())
)

print(res_df)

     max_val  min_val    std_val  pct_total
Foo                                        
A         98       25  31.040296   0.585809
B         90       25  25.371244   0.414191
```

Or use `round(x.sum()/temp.Bar.sum(),2)` if you want them rounded: `0.59, 0.41`.